# Batch URL parsing with powershell passed variables

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs off a powershell command I created, and I want to make it so you can pass a variable from the PS command to a website url query..

My problem is that the variables I pass from PS are referenced in batch as %1, %2, %n

now I set these variables at the beginning to more meaningful named variables, but in my url eg: www.google.com/myQuery%20has%20spaces would print out my %2 variable from PS instead of a space.

Is there anyway to clear out the %1,%2 variables that are passed? or any work around?

edit: I have tried a simple set %1= to try and set it as a null variable but it didn't work.

Comment: I have actually figured out you can escape the % in the string with a %% in batch, so this question is no longer needed. Thanks

Comment: You may want to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the % in the string with a %% in batch, which solves the issue.